# Exchange server not sending email to internet

Tags: email, exchange-2007

i have implemented one exchange server 2007 in my home.
i have created few users and i am able to send and receive email on these users.

but when i try to send email to any user outside that server, i can't send email.

is there any special setting for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would one consider a question about server email delivery issues a "super user" question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you created the send connector?

Comment: No i did't created the send connector...
can you tell me how to do this...

Comment: http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/11/17/431555.aspx